# Finding duplicate strings in object using $.map

Tags: javascript, jquery

From following code I am expecting that `elist` will contain each string in `er` only once. I mean `elist` will have unique value of `er`. But I am not getting unique strings in `elist`. Whats wrong here?

```
i = 0; 
elist = "";
$.map(er, function(value, key){                          
    if ( isDuplicate(value, er, i) < 0 ) {
        elist += value;  
    }
    $("#"+key).addClass('has-error');
    i += 1;
});

function isDuplicate(str, er_, offset){
    j = 0; 
    return_val = -1

    $.map(er_, function(value, key){
        alert(j +'>'+offset+'------'+value+'=='+str);
        if ( j > offset && value == str){
            return_val = j;
            alert('matched');
        }
        j += 1;
    });

    return return_val;
}
```

Comment: How do the contents of `er` variable look like?

Comment: er={a:"a",b:"b",c:"b"}

Answer (score 0):

You can use something more simple like this:

```
var arr=[];
$.map(er, function(value, key){           
    if   ( arr.indexOf(value) == -1 ) 
   {arr.push(value);}
});
alert(arr.join());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7cohow41/3/

Comment: if ( arr.indexOf(value) == -1 ) {arr.push(value);} looks simpler

Comment: Thanks, fixed with indexOf

Comment: This is much better alternative but I just want to know error in my code